# R - How to reduce the frequency of appearance of pch in plot?

Tags: r

I would like to plot several time series, with each line showing pch. However, the pch appears on each data point, is there any way I can reduce the frequency of pch appearing on the line, say one pch appears every several data point so that the lines won't appear as a thick line packed with pch?

Comment: Why not use a line graph (`type = 'l'`) and then vary the colour or type of the line instead?

Comment: you can plot a subset of the data, using e.g. `d[seq(1, nrow(d), by=10), ]`

Comment: A reproducible example would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach that might help you. It's hard to know for sure without more details about what you want your output to look like.

```
x = seq(0, 20, 0.1)

par(mfrow=c(2, 1))

plot(x, x^2, pch=1, main="Before")
points(x, x*10, pch=2)

plot(x, x^2, pch=c(1, rep(NA, 9)), main="After")
points(x, x*10, pch=c(2, rep(NA, 9)))
```

[image]